# Why doesn't this button appear?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Hi I have created this button in a Java program and for some reason the button  doesn't appear. (This button is part of a larger program and there are more buttons and they are put in the exact same way and they do appear, I have took them out just to make it easier to read the code).

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

 public GUI() {

  JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Button");
    add(btnNewButton);
  btnNewButton.setBounds(518, 272, 216, 45);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  GUI menu = new GUI();
  menu.setVisible(true);
  menu.setTitle("GUI");
  menu.setBounds(0, 0, 780, 500);
  menu.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  menu.setLayout(null);
 }
}
```

Comment: You should add this button in any JFrame or JPanel...

Comment: Don't use a null layout. Don't use setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for working examples to get you stated. The tutorial also has a section on `Layout Managers`, so you can play with different layout managers. And your GUI should be created on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. Again all the tutorial examples show how to do this. So start with working examples.

Comment: @Amit he extends GUI with JFrame

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but like the rest of my code works , all the other buttons work using this method, this is the only button that doesn't work like I just want to fix the button I don't want critique on my coding style

Comment: try to use `menu.revalidate()`

Comment: (1-) `all the other buttons work using this method` - what buttons???. Your code only has a single button. In any case whether is works or not is really irrelevant. The code is wrong and will cause problems in the future. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers for too many reasons to list here.  `I just want to fix the button I don't want critique on my coding style` -  We are here to give advice on the proper way to code a Swing GUI.  We don't have time to continually answer questions because of your poor coding style. **Read the tutorials!!!**

Answer (score 0):

Use your setVibile after you have done everything else

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

 public GUI() {

  JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Button");
    add(btnNewButton);
  btnNewButton.setBounds(518, 272, 216, 45);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  GUI menu = new GUI();

  menu.setTitle("GUI");
  menu.setBounds(0, 0, 780, 500);
  menu.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  menu.setLayout(null); 
  menu.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

Comment: Instead of just showing the fixed code, I would suggest you also include some text explaining why it wasn't working, and why this change fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to `pack()` the button to your `JFrame`. Try this:

```
public GUI() {

  JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Button");
    add(btnNewButton);
  btnNewButton.setBounds(518, 272, 216, 45);
  pack();
 }
```